# Styling Vuedraggle elements

Tags: vue.js, vuedraggable

I'm using `vuedraggable` to build a kanban board (Trello like) and it works fine, but I'm stuck in styling it the way I want.

In fact I'd like to have this kind of animation ([LINK](https://kutlugsahin.github.io/vue-smooth-dnd/#/cards)) :

[image]

So I want to be able to :

- Move the card itself and not a sort of shadow copy of itself
- Style the drop placeholder like this.

What are the classes that I should aim at modifying (with css) ? It isn't very clear in the docs in my opinion.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: The documentation shows a prop called `ghost-class`. My feeling says that this is the thing you are looking for. You can then style that however you want.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Yes but it displays a copy of  the card too. What I'd like is to do like on the image. Is that possible not to display the card but something else with CSS ? CSS is not my best thing.

Comment: The example you linked provides the full source, which already answers your question.

Answer (score 3):

You want to do a couple of things. The default ghost image is something that the browser does by default. We can't make that opaque though, so we want to get rid of it. To do this, listen to the `dragstart` event, and set the drag image to an empty image:

```js
event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(new Image(), 0, 0);
```

Now that we have that out of the way, we need to make the dragged image. To both get an indication of where the item will be dropped, and the actual card you are dropping, I think you can best just duplicate the card that is being moved into a temporary container that you can manipulate. You then figure out where the mouse is and move the temporary container around. At the end you want to remove the temporary card, so you don't end up with a random card somewhere on the screen.

Your template would look something like this:

```
<draggable v-model="items" animation="150">
  <div
    v-for="item in items"
    :key="item"
    class="item"
    @dragstart="dragStartHandler"
    @dragend="dragEndHandler"
    @drag="dragHandler"
  >{{ item }}</div>
</draggable>

<div class="drag-preview" :style="dragStyle" ref="dragPreview"></div>
```

We can use `dragstart` and `dragend` to both set the empty placeholder, and add and remove a duplicated card

```js
dragStartHandler(e) {
  this.dragPreview = e.target.cloneNode(true);
  this.$refs["dragPreview"].appendChild(this.dragPreview);

  e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(new Image(), 0, 0);
},

dragEndHandler() {
  this.dragPreview.remove();
  this.dragPreview = null;
},
```

The `drag` event is an extended MouseEvent, which has screen and page coordinates. We listen to it to figure out where the mouse is, and just update some variables with them.

```js
dragHandler(e) {
  this.x = e.pageX;
  this.y = e.pageY;
}
```

You can then compute your top and left coordinates, by simply appending `px` to them

```js
dragStyle() {
  return {
    top: `${this.y}px`,
    left: `${this.x}px`
  };
}
```

To style this all, the item that is currently being sorted has the `sortable-ghost` class by default. In my case, I just gave it a gray dashed outline, and set the font-size to 0 to hide the text.

```css
.sortable-ghost {
  border: 1px dashed grey;
  font-size: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

The `drag-preview` class is what follows the mouse around. Of course, nothing is in there when you are not dragging anything. Your example shows a slightly tilted card, so we translate the card 50% to the top and left, so it is centered on our mouse. We then rotate it slightly by 7 degrees. Finally we move it down by 55% so it does not intersect with our mouse.

```css
.drag-preview {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(7deg) translateY(55%);
}
```

[image: Edit Styling Vuedraggable elements]

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Sumurai8 . I'll test it and let you know :).